# grunt-protractor-runner not working correctly

Tags: gruntjs, protractor

My case is similar to case from other question

"I use protractor to test my angular app. When I manually launch protractor it works properly and tests everything but the trouble comes when I try to launch it through grunt.

When I launch my grunt task for testing, protractor finds the conf file (it displays the right number of specs to test) but just open the chrome driver for less than a seconds on a weird "data;" url, close it right away and marks all the tests as "passed"."

grunt-cli v1.2.0
grunt v0.4.5
node v6.4.0
protractor 4.0.4

```
module.exports = function () {
return {
protractor: {
  options: {
    // Location of your protractor config file
    configFile: "test/protractor.conf.js",
    noColor: false,

  },
  e2e: {
    options: {
      // Stops Grunt process if a test fails
      keepAlive: false
    }
  },
  continuous: {
    options: {
      keepAlive: true
    }
   }
  }
 }
};
```

This is my config for grunt

Answer (score 0):

Not have a direct answer to your question, but here is what we have set up that works for us.

Here are the relevant dependencies (note that we had to ["fork" `grunt-protractor-runner`](https://github.com/alecxe/grunt-protractor-runner/commit/a7916108f42b466cb15c611d32be24bae5f8650c) to bump the `protractor` dependency):

```
"grunt-protractor-runner": "git+https://github.com/alecxe/grunt-protractor-runner.git",
"protractor": "^4.0.0",
```

Here is the relevant part of grunt config:

```
protractor: {
    options: {
        keepAlive: true,
        noColor: false
    },
    remote: {
        options: {
            configFile: "test/e2e/config/remote.conf.js"
        }
    },
    local: {
        options: {
            configFile: "test/e2e/config/local.conf.js"
        }
    }
},
```

And, we run our tests through `grunt e2e:local` and `grunt e2e:remote`.

---

Also, make sure to have the latest `chromedriver` downloaded via `webdriver-manager update`.